# Change element properties in new thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement a button; which changes its label to "Signing in...", keeps that label until an event gets completed, then it changes its label to old one again. But in this interval, it shouldn't freeze (basically UI thread will continue to execute). What kind of algorithm can be performed here? I just used this code but it's not working expectedly:

```
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                string old_label = sign_in_button.label.Content;
    

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                new Action(() => {

                    sign_in_button.label.Content = "Signing in...";
               
                }));

                // Event gets executed here...
                

                sign_in_button.label.Content = old_label;
            });
```

Comment: You have obviously two invalid cross-thread operations by accessing your `sign_in_button` from your background thread. You should access it always using the Dispatcher, like you do it once. But what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: It basically doesn't change the content of label, I also put a MessageBox after old_label definition, and it didn't get executed.

Comment: This is bacause the first code line is accessing your button from a background thread which throws an exception. You don't await your task, so the exception is 'lost'. Try the way as suggested by @Lingam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async await. Sample code below. You can also pass in your mainwindow dispatcher to your new thread, in case you are planning to update or fetch some UI data from there.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _dispatcher = App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher;
        string old_label = sign_in_button.Content as string;
        sign_in_button.Content = "Signing in...";

        // Event gets executed here...
        await Task.Run(() => signIn(_dispatcher));
        sign_in_button.Content = old_label;
    }

    private void signIn(Dispatcher _dispatcher)
    {
        //THREAD DELAY TEST
        Thread.Sleep(3500);

        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { sign_in_button.Content = "Changed from another thread"; },DispatcherPriority.Send);

        Thread.Sleep(3500);
    }
```

Comment: That's right. I think I had missunderstanding about what dispatcher is, before. Now I figured out how it's exactly used. Thanks.